# Group Employee for each Department

Tags: sql, sql-server, grouping, group-concat

I have a table `Details`

```
DeptId        EmpID
-------      ---------
1             1
1             5
1             3
2             8
2             9
```

I want to group them like this:

```
DeptId      EmpIDs
-------    -------
 1          1,5,3
 2          8,9
```

I want this in SQL Server. I know this can be done in MySQL using `Group_Concat` function. e.g.

```
SELECT DeptId, GROUP_CONCAT(EmpId SEPARATOR ',') EmpIDS
FROM Details GROUP BY DeptId
```

[(SQL Fiddle here)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/89baa/1)

But how to do this with SQL Server? I don't know any function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to simulate `GROUP_CONCAT` in `SQLServer` is to use `CROSS APPLY` and `FOR XML PATH()`

```
select a.[DeptId], SUBSTRING(d.detailsList,1, LEN(d.detailsList) - 1) detailsList
from 
  (
    SELECT DISTINCT [DeptId]
    FROM details
  ) a
CROSS APPLY
  (
    SELECT [EmpID] + ', ' 
    FROM details AS B 
    WHERE A.[DeptId] = B.[DeptId]
    FOR XML PATH('')
  ) D (detailsList)
```

- [***See SQLFiddle Demo***](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b35ef/2)
- [***See SQLFiddle Demo*** ***(order by EmpID)***](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b35ef/5)