# Row data to column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have sql query to get locations for files

```
select FileName, FileLocation from tblFile
```

and data like

```
FileName               FileLocation

file1                  \\server1\folder1\file1
file1                  \\server2\folder1\file1
file2                  \\server1\folder1\file2
file2                  \\server2\folder1\file2
```

I would like to get data like:

```
FileName               FileLocations

file1                  \\server1\folder1\file1, \\server2\folder1\file1
file2                  \\server1\folder1\file2, \\server2\folder1\file2
```

How can I get above result in sql server?

Comment: What is the Primary Key on your table?

Comment: It's FileLocationID. Actually table is FileLocationID, FileID, LocationID. For simplicity, just mentioned actual readable (foreign key) columns.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Group Employee for each Department](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13132571/group-employee-for-each-department)

Comment: you can use COALESCE [See this link](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/06/04/sql-server-create-a-comma-delimited-list-using-select-clause-from-table-column/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/51e01/1)

**MS SQL Server 2008 Schema Setup**:

```
create table tblFile
(
  FileName varchar(10),
  FileLocation varchar(30)
)

insert into tblFile values
('file1',                  '\\server1\folder1\file1'),
('file1',                  '\\server2\folder1\file1'),
('file2',                  '\\server1\folder1\file2'),
('file2',                  '\\server2\folder1\file2')
```

**Query 1**:

```
select T1.FileName,
       (
       select ', '+T2.FileLocation
       from tblFile as T2
       where T1.FileName = T2.FileName
       for xml path(''), type
       ).value('substring(text()[1], 3)', 'varchar(max)') as FileLocations
from tblFile as T1
group by T1.FileName
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/51e01/1/0)**:

```
| FILENAME |                                    FILELOCATIONS |
---------------------------------------------------------------
|    file1 | \\server1\folder1\file1, \\server2\folder1\file1 |
|    file2 | \\server1\folder1\file2, \\server2\folder1\file2 |
```